# Can't Access Node.JS over internet

Tags: node.js, express, firewall, nat

I'm trying to access a simple node.js/express application over the internet, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working. I can access it using http://localhost:3000 and http://192.168.x.x:3000 but not using my external IP address.

Port 3000 is open on my router (double checked with port online port checker tools), and I've added a rule in the firewall to allow the port (Windows 10).

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0")
```

netstat seems to suggest that port 3000 is allowed through the firewall, right?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -n -a

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Comment: Please provide the domain name & share your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file content

Comment: @VimalMahi I'm not using a domain name at the moment. Just trying to use my external ip address. My hosts file is just the default generated by windows. Everything's commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue! It has to do with me testing the connection inside of the LAN on a router that doesn't support hairpinning ([see point 2 in this stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/questions/987174/port-is-open-but-cant-access-it-via-external-ip-address#answer-987191)). Simply accessing the application on a device outside of my LAN does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward that port or make a tunnel to use it over internet . By default the ports are blocked. The problem is not the server is not listening the problem is that it is not discoverable from the outside.

- To forward the port, Add the forward rule to your router [[More info]](https://portforward.com/)
- For tunnelling you can use [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/)

By doing that you can connect to the server at `http://<your_external_ip>:<forwarded_port>`

Comment: Port 3000 is open on my router (double checked with port online port checker tools). I looked into ngrok, but I don't want to pay for a static url. I really don't want to use tunneling.

Comment: what is the url that you are using? you are using your external IP right? (the ip that can be found by searching "what is my ip" in google)

Comment: Correct. I'm using my external ip address without a domain.

Comment: Then maybe it is blocked by ISP. Router on the upper level of your router is blocking the traffic.

Comment: canyouseeme.org wouldn't be able to see the open port then, right? It's telling me port 3000 is open.